# Unable to populate BD whit ConfigBean and @RunAs

Tags: jax-rs, ejb, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I'm using ConfigBean in order to populate my BD, like so:

```
@Singleton
@Startup 
@RunAs("Administrator")
public class ConfigBean {

    @EJB
    private ClientBean clientBean;

    @EJB
    private AdministratorBean adminstratorBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateDB() {
        try{
            clientBean.create(new ClientDTO("client1", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Av. José Maceda", "918 923 232"));
            clientBean.create(new ClientDTO("client2", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Av. Alberto Alves", "+00351 256 0033 12"));
            adminstratorBean.create(new AdministratorDTO("administrator1", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Director"));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Both my beans look like so:

```
@POST
@RolesAllowed("Administrator")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response create(AdministratorDTO administratorDTO){...}
```

As for my web.xml:

```
...
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>dae_project_realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Client</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Everything seems ok. However, when I run the application and the method populateDB is called, I keep getting the error:

```
javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
```

I saw a few interesting links, but I still couldn't get it to work:

- [Can't get @RunAs to work in an EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118280/cant-get-runas-to-work-in-an-ejb) (option doesn't exist)
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/175108 (Not a fan of a timer and was unable to call the route from @WebServlet)
- https://samaxes.com/2014/11/test-javaee-security-with-arquillian/ (Couldn't make it work, plus I still not sure if I could use this to populate the BD.)
- [Using a secured EJB from a JAX-RS web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855125/using-a-secured-ejb-from-a-jax-rs-web-service?rq=1) (Solution doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use @RunAs, we need to create a user of that role. 
For that, you need to do the following steps.

1. Open GlashFish in Admin Console
2. Open Configurations>server-config>security>realms
3. Click on file
   [image]
4. Click on Manage Users
   [image]
5. Click in New
6. Create the User like so:
   [image]
7. Update @RunAs to use the new created user:

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Startup 
   @RunAs("BOB") //BOB belongs to the desired group 
   public class ConfigBean {

       @EJB
       private ClientBean clientBean;

       @EJB
       private AdministratorBean adminstratorBean;

       @PostConstruct
       public void populateDB() {
           try{
               clientBean.create(new ClientDTO("client1", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Av. José Maceda", "918 923 232"));
               clientBean.create(new ClientDTO("client2", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Av. Alberto Alves", "+00351 256 0033 12"));
               adminstratorBean.create(new AdministratorDTO("administrator1", "secret", "Manuel", "dae.ei.ipleiria@gmail.com", "Director"));
           }catch(Exception ex){
               System.out.println(ex);
           }
       }
   ```